# C# retry method interception with free a AOP framework

Tags: c#, aop

I'm totally new to the AOP in C#. Currently, I'm interested to write a retry for a method that uses this technique.

So, based on the postsharp tut: https://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception 
I've written this code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class RetryAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private int _sleep;
    private int _retries;
    private object _expectedResult;
    private object _defaultReturnValue;

    public RetryAspect(object expectedResult, int waitBetweenCycles, int numberOfRetries) : this(expectedResult, waitBetweenCycles, numberOfRetries, null) { }

    public RetryAspect(object expectedResult, int waitBetweenCycles, int numberOfRetries, object defaultReturnValue)
    {
        _expectedResult = expectedResult;
        _sleep = waitBetweenCycles;
        _retries = numberOfRetries;
        _defaultReturnValue = defaultReturnValue;
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        int waitCount = 0;

        while (!args.ReturnValue.Equals(_expectedResult))
        {
            args.Proceed();

            if (waitCount++ < _retries)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_sleep);
            }
            else
            {
                if (_defaultReturnValue != null)
                {
                    args.ReturnValue = _defaultReturnValue;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static int cnt = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [RetryAspect(true, 1000, 5)]
    public static bool Test()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Test {0}", cnt);
            if (cnt == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                cnt++;
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Now, is there a way to achieve the same result by using a free/open source AOP framework? So far, I didn't found any useful example with a different AOP framework.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is exactly, it would be helpful to explain that before/after the code that you included. I have had success using AutoFac which is primarily a DI/IoC framework *but* has the ability to intercept calls to registered types.

Answer (score 0):

Althogh it is not AOP I can suggest you to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly):

> Polly is a .NET resilience and transient-fault-handling library that allows developers to express policies such as Retry ...

You will just need to define your policy using it's fluent API:

```
var policy = Policy
              .HandleResult<bool>(false)
              //Or using one of WaitAndRetry overloads if you want to sleep between retries 
              .Retry(5);
```

And execute it:

```
policy.Execute(() => Test());
```